# Over-the-border murder consequences

Tags: international

Two countries A and B share the border. For simplicity let the border pass along the river so that it is easily legally accessible from both sides and people from two countries can see each another.

A sniper stands near the border at country A and lethally shoots someone at the other side (at country B). How can this act be classified in legal terms?

1. Who will investigate the case? In [United States citizen crosses Canadian border and murders someone. Who prosecutes the killer?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/53639/united-states-citizen-crosses-canadian-border-and-murders-someone-who-prosecute) a reminiscent situation is raised. Quoting the answer: *Canada would investigate the case, because it is a murder on Canadian ground*. Has the murder in my question happened on A's ground (since the act of killing was initiated from there) or on B's ground (since the victim was there at the moment of being injured)?
2. If there is no extradition from A to B (or some kind of immunity applies), can it happen that the shooter avoids the prosecution completely? Here I mean the prosecution for the murder only; the shooter may have violated other laws like owning the weapon illegally or using it in public, this clearly is internal for country A and is out of scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Both countries A and B have their laws. If the laws are well-designed, the murderer will go to court in one of the countries and will go to jail in one of the countries, and who does the investigation and which country he or she ends up in is secondary.

If the laws are not so well designed then both countries will want to put the murderer into jail. Often the second country will not prosecute further if the murderer ever leaves jail. And if the laws are badly designed, it could be that neither country takes responsibility.

This could happen if country A's laws say that the country where the shooter pulls the trigger should prosecute, and country B's laws says that the country where the bullet hits the victim should prosecute. (Both versions are quite sensible, but you'd want say USA and Canada or USA and Mexico to apply the same rules). Of course a country could also say that it prosecutes if you pull the trigger in country A *or* the bullet hits the victim in country A.

Comment: Often, in cases where no extradition is possible (citizen of country A cannot be extradited), the person would be charged as if it took place in country A (with cooperation of country B).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how this answers the question. It basically just says, "it depends on what the law says," which seems to be what the OP asking in the first place.

Comment: @bdb484 Can you point me to where the country is managed in the question? Can't see it. And I assume the person asking isn't interested in two specific countries, but the general principle.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from gnasher729 with examples:

- Many (but not all) countries reserve the right to try one of their citizens for murder, regardless of where that murder happened. Such rules are often restricted to major crimes; a few decades ago there were efforts to include [sexual offenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_tourism#Child_sex_tourism) on this list. The webpage [Policy paper Extraterritorial jurisdiction factsheet](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/domestic-abuse-bill-2020-factsheets/extraterritorial-jurisdiction-factsheet) is an example for the UK.
- Many (but not all) countries reserve the right to try crimes against one of their citizens or even foreigners abroad, as long as they get hold of the suspect. The webpage [1617. Extraterritorial Criminal Jurisdiction -- 18 U.S.C. §112, 878, 970, 1116, 1117 And 1201](https://www.justice.gov/archives/jm/criminal-resource-manual-1617-extraterritorial-criminal-jurisdiction-18-usc-112-878-970-1116) is an example for the US.
- This can in theory lead to double punishment of an offender. Preventing such double punishment is a complex legislative undertaking. The paper [A Reasoned Approach to Prohibiting the Bis in Idem](https://eucrim.eu/articles/a-reasoned-approach-to-prohibiting-the-bis-in-idem/) is an example of EU efforts to avoid duplication.

Comment: In five years, or at some point sooner or later, nobody is going to have any idea what you're linking to behind those "here" links.

Comment: @phoog, you're right, I can make it somewhat more friendly for people who google. But if the page is gone rather than moved, can they find it?

Comment: @phoog Actually, anyone who can edit to get the URL, even behind a "here" link, can often find the former contents via the Internet Archive or other archive sites -- I got to be pretty good at this fixing dead links on Wikipedia. They have a page on how to do this. Of course not all pages are archived by any site. .Knowing the intended content can help find it if it has been moved, of course.

Comment: @DavidSiegel sure, but does the author of an answer want to make users have to go through that to know what they're trying to say?  A day or two ago I stumbled across an answer with a couple of "here" links that were truly obscure -- the URLs consisted only of numeric document identifiers on a couple of different academic paper sites.  I didn't check whether they're available in the internet archive.

Comment: @phoog Perhaps we should take this to meta? Of course the more stable a link destination is, the better. I just wanted to point out that it is often possible to recover the content o a broken link, even if no title or author was given in the text of a post here. That does not mean this is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

### Laws try to deal with this

For example, [new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales) Crimes Act [s10A](https://epiphany.law/articles/articles/trademark-non-use) (note the “A” which means it was clearly added later to deal with some problem):

> **10A   Application and effect of Part**
>
> (1)  This Part applies to all offences.
>
> (2)  This Part extends, beyond the territorial limits of the State, the application of a law of the State that creates an offence if there is the nexus required by this Part between the State and the offence.
>
> (3)  If the law that creates an offence makes provision with respect to any geographical consideration concerning the offence, that provision prevails over any inconsistent provision of this Part.
>
> (4)  This Part is in addition to and does not derogate from any other basis on which the courts of the State may exercise criminal jurisdiction.

This would capture a shooter inQueensland and a victim in NSW and vice-versa but excludes any offence where the law limits its jurisdiction to NSW, unless the courts would have jurisdiction under common law.

The equivalent [law](https://www.legislation.qld.gov.au/view/pdf/inforce/current/act-1899-009) in [queensland](/questions/tagged/queensland) would also make it an offence there even though it is not couched in the same terms.

A person could be convicted in NSW, serve their senescence, be extradited to Queensland, be convicted and serve the sentence there. As a matter of public policy, this wouldn’t happen, one state would take the lead and the other would support the investigation/prosecution.

Of course, poorly drafted laws might mean that one or both might not have jurisdiction.

Similarly, political considerations might supervene: a cross-border murder between Ukraine and Russia is unlikely to be prosecuted effectively in the present circumstances.